# How can I use the az --query command to list all of the json fields but not their values? eg. az account list --query <something>

Tags: json, azure, azure-cli, jmespath, azure-cloud-shell

I'm looking for an 'az' --query syntax that just lists the json fields and not their values.

this will print a table:

```
az account list --query [*] -o --table

Name    State  IsDefault  TenantId    CloudName

----    -----  ---------  --------    ---------

bob     Enabled True       nnn        AzureCloud
```

but I don't want the values under the column names, I just want a list of the column names.

Comment: I dont think you can do anything like that with just azure cli, lets maybe take a step back, why do you need that?

Comment: So I can identify the available fields without digging though the json.

Comment: ... obviously, but why do you need that?

Answer (score 4):

### Context

- MSFT azure cloud shell console (as of 2019-11-17)
- azure cloud shell `az` commands with queries

### Use-case

- User_broglock wants a query to return the field-names (and not field-values) from the output result of a cloud shell `az account list` command

### Solution

- complete command

```
az account list --query '@|[0]|keys(@)|[*].{"FieldName":@}' --output table
```

- demo result

```
FieldName
-----------
id
name
state
user
isDefault
tenantId
cloudName
```

### Explanation

- The Azure CLI uses the `--query` argument to execute a [JMESPath](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jmespath/info) query
- JMESPath supports the `keys()` function, which returns the names in a JSON name-value-pair object (aka `dictionary`) (aka `associative array`) (aka `HashTable`)
- After extracting with `keys()` we return the result as a list of name-value pairs: `{"Fieldname":<CurrentItemFromList>}` ... this essentially gives us a table with one column.

#### Diagram

[image: Diagramuu0283bluhoyaz-001aa]

### See also

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/query-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: @broglock NOTE: The initial `@|` at-sign and pipe is not actually required, however some choose to write queries this way.

Comment: you're brilliant, thanks! That's EXACTLY what I'm looking for.

Comment: broglock , you did not upvote or accepted the answer

Comment: Something must have changed in the last several years, I tried that complete command and I just get `'[0]' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`. None of the variations suggested work either. Back to the drawing board...